# How to check the interaction of LSD at Strip Plot Design; strip.plot() in R?

Tags: r

This is my data.

```
github<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agronomy4future/raw_data_practice/main/strip_plot.csv"
dataA<-data.frame(read_csv(url(github)))
```

and I'd like to analyze my data as strip plot design. So I used the below code, and obtained the result.

```
library(agricolae)

attach(dataA)
model<- strip.plot(BLOCK=rep,
                   COL=treatment,
                   ROW=fertilzier,
                   Y=yield)

Response: yield
                     Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
rep                   3 0.6939 0.23130                 
treatment             2 1.8003 0.90014  3.0537 0.1217  
Ea                    6 1.7686 0.29477                 
fertilzier            5 1.9294 0.38589  0.8467 0.5378  
Eb                   15 6.8361 0.45574                 
fertilzier:treatment 10 3.4847 0.34847  2.5092 0.0251 *
Ec                   30 4.1664 0.13888                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

cv(a) = 3.6 %, cv(b) = 4.5 %, cv(c) = 2.5 %, Mean = 15.14722
```

I found the interaction between treatment and fertilizer. So, I'd like to check the LSD about the interaction. So, I used the below code.

```
LSD_AB = LSD.test(y = yield,
                  trt = treatment:fertilzier,
                  DFerror = model$gl.c,
                  MSerror = model$Ec,
                  alpha = 0.05,
                  p.adj = "bonferroni",
                  group = TRUE,
                  console = TRUE)
```

but there is an error message.

```
Error in treatment:fertilzier : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In treatment:fertilzier :
  numerical expression has 72 elements: only the first used
2: In treatment:fertilzier :
  numerical expression has 72 elements: only the first used
3: In data.frame(y, trt) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In data.frame(y, trt) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

Always thansk,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My problem was that my two variables were not factors. When you load your csv, use the argument `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`

You can only use the concatenate ":" on two factor variables otherwise R throws you errors. Once I fixed my variables to be factors I was able to do the interaction LSD test.